# thunderbird not updated to 52.3 on xubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, xubuntu, thunderbird

I have a xubuntu 16.04 with thunderbird running. Because there where some news about serious security problems with thunderbird before 52.3 I checked if my system has been properly updated. But thunderbird version is still 52.2.1 even after `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't exist any update yet in the official repositories, for any release. 52.2.1 is the latest version you can get.

See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=thunderbird

You have to wait until a package update is provided. If there really is a security threat, this will probably happen pretty quickly.

If you are really concerned, you might e.g. try finding a PPA or installing Thunderbird from source, but I don't think it will be worth the hassle.